# if condition evaluation in javascript using eval at runtime

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

```
 var y = 1;

 if (function f(){}) {
   y += typeof f;
 }
 console.log(y);
```

The Output of this code is `1undefined`. I get the reason that the condition in `if` statement is evaluated using `eval` at runtime, but I cannot understand why it is not outputting `1function`.

Comment: FWIW, Microsoft Edge outputs `1object`

Comment: It's not `eval`'d at all. It's a *function expression*. The same as `if ('foo')`. There's no way to access that *string expression* `'foo'` either, because it's just an expression not assigned to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function outside the if braces, if not, the scope of `f` is restricted to the inside of the condition.
If you reformulate like this it works:

```
var y = 1;
//Pick One:
var f = () => {}; //If you are using ES6

function f() {}; //If you are not using ES6

if (f) {
  y += typeof f;
}

console.log(y); // 1function
```

Answer (score -1):

In your example, the function is only scoped within the brackets of the test condition of the `if` statement.

Try the following:

```js
  var y = 1;
  var f = function() { };
  if (f) {
    y += typeof f;
  }
  console.log(y)
```

You can define the function in the if test if the pointer to function is defined outside.

```js
      var y = 1;
      var f = null;
      if (f = function() { }) {
        y += typeof f;
      }
      console.log(y)
```

Comment: i Understand example given by you.But what is mean by scope with in brackets and even if it is scope with in bracket then why in " y += typeof f;" typeof f is undefined?It should give reference error.

Comment: It's not scoped "within the if statement", it's not scoped anywhere. It's the same as `if ('foo')`. You cannot access the `'foo'` anywhere either.

Comment: With 'if (function f () { })'.  Javascript will see that yes, this is a function and therefore the test result will be true.  But f no longer exists once the test completes.  So f is undefined and has no type within the if code block.

Comment: `f` *never* existed anywhere, because it's a *function expression*, not a *function declaration.*

Comment: @StephenHewison ,if it would have given me reference error then i would have assumed that there is not variable in any scope with name 'f'.But if typeof f is undefined it means that there is variable in some scope. and acccording to es6 functions declaration are block scope.According to your answer But f no longer exists once the test completes.' if it does not exist it should have given refernce error.What is the real concept behind this functionality?

Comment: @Suraj `f` and `typeof f` are two different things. `typeof` never throws a reference error.

Comment: Thanks,@stephen & @deceze ,now i got the answer 'typeof' never throws error because of 'IsUnresolvableReference' .